# Use Stored Procedure Select Query Result to DataGridView - DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I want to use select query from stored procedure to Datagridview Datasource.
When I run my code, nothing happens. No data displayed on my datagrid view. Help Thanks.

```
Event:
protected void Emplvl_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvCategoryList.DataSource = mav.GetCategories2(Emplvl.SelectedValue.ToString());
    dgvCategoryList.DataBind();
}
```

Method:

```
    public DataTable GetCategories2(string eelvl2)
{
    SysCon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdCC = new SqlCommand("sp_SearchEmployeeCategory", SysCon);
    cmdCC.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdCC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLEVEL", eelvl2);
    SqlDataAdapter daCC = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdCC);
    DataTable dsC = new DataTable();
    daCC.Fill(dsC);
    SysCon.Close();
    return dsC;
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchEmployeeCategory] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@EMPLEVEL NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT EmpCategory
FROM tbl_13Month_Computation
WHERE EmpLevel = @EMPLEVEL
END
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this code? In particular did you check what value is passed to the _GetCategories2_ method?

Comment: I don't know which DB Type you use but looks like you don't have out parameter in your stored procedure. This procedure must be working, but no data returns. You should create **out** parameter and get data in c#. If i were you, i would use only select command, not stored procedure.

Comment: I already fixed it. Thank you for response. I just forgot to remove AutoGenerateColumn Property. Can you tell me if  there is any conflict using AutoGenerateColumn Property tp datasources binding? Thank you